# Make Python class variable follow the value of the object that it was assigned to

Tags: python, class, class-variables

I've been working on a project, but I've ran into a problem; When I change the value of an item, it doesn't change the value of the variable in other places where it has been used. I know this is standard Python behavior, but I don't want that in this case.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2, p3):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
        self.p3 = p3

class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.points = [\
            Point(x),
            Point(x + 1),
            Point(x + 2)
        ]

        self.triangles = [\
            Triangle(self.points[0], self.points[1], self.points[2])
        ]

someShape = Shape(10)
someShape.points[0] = Point(30) # Change the first point in self.points

print(someShape.triangles[0].p1.pos)
# 10
```

Feel free to try out the code. It's an simplification of what I actually have. I want `someShape.triangles[0].p1` to change to the new version of `someShape.points[0]` to which is was assigned originally. Is there any way to do this? Do I need to approach this differently? Each `Point()` **has** to be it's own object. I don't want a list with in the triangles an index of the point it has.

Thank you!

Comment: Change `self.triangles` to a property that recreates the triangles on every access?

Comment: I guess that would work, but isn't there really not any other way? What if I had thousands of these ```Shape(s)()``` in a list? I'd hope it wouln't slow down too much. Does it take python long to create new objects?

Comment: There isn't really any better way. Python doesn't have any way to make a permanent reference to a list element.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how your program runs but yes it could negatively impact performance. How often will you be changing points in shapes? You could make self.points immutable and then a mechanism for updating points like a setter than that recalculated triangles

Comment: I agree. They don't all update every frame, if i would make an ```update(self)``` function, and called it every time it's position was changed I'd think that that would be good enough. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you choose self.triangles to be a list?

Comment: I did that, so i could just loop over ```foo.triangles``` when rendering it to the screen.